# SEBI RULE For Closed Company / Share not traded

Tags: stocks, india, stock-markets

I have Invested good amount in SUPREME TEX (BSE: 531934).. This company is not traded from last two month. What is the SEBI rule to for refund ?

Answer (score 1):

SEBI doesn't refund money for shares. It regulates the exchange.

The company has lost value and SEBI has stopped trading on exchange.

Given that it's book value is negative, I doubt if you can find any offline buyer's